# Using Checkbox To Select Row In DataGridView VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, datagridview

I am fairly new to VB.Net so please excuse the elementary question. I am using a DataGridView to display data that the user will select full rows of the data. I have added a checkbox column (first column) for the user to visually see the rows that were selected. I am trying to set that if the checkbox is selected then the row is selected and if the row is selected then the checkbox is selected. Consequently I am trying to get the opposite to be true for unselecting.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CbxRowSelect(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
    Dim CellChecked As DataGridViewCheckBoxCell = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0)
    Dim SelectedRow As DataGridViewRow = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)

    If CellChecked.Value = True Then
        SelectedRow.Selected = True
    End If
    If CellChecked.Value = False Then
        SelectedRow.Selected = False
    End If
    If SelectedRow.SelectedCell = True Then
        Checked.Value= True
    End If
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: Given that selected rows are highlighted, I'm not quite sure why you feel the need to add a check box for visual feedback. This sounds a bit like "because I can" to me, but it's your prerogative.

Comment: Is the check box column unbound in a bound grid?

Comment: As already commented, it is unclear “why” you would want to introduce a check box column for this. If the user does NOT click on the check box in a particular row… do you want the row to NOT be selected? And if so… “why”? This is counter intuitive.

Comment: In addition, it appears you are using the grids `CellContentClick` event and this is fine. However, the code NEVER checks to see if the check box cell is the cell triggering this event. This event will also fire if the user clicked into some other cell. The code is re-selecting or re-un-selecting the cells unnecessarily since the check box was NOT necessarily changed.

Comment: The reason why is that there are hundreds of rows and there are many references in the current project that refers to the 'selected rows'. So having a checkbox was recommended. I am unsure how to tell if the column is bound or unbound. The column was created through the properties tab and the data that feeds into the dgv is from a local table to which is inserted by row/column. Additionally @JohnG do you have any recommendation to fixes so that when a row is selected the checkbox is checked and vice-versa. Sorry I am still new to VB, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You commented that… _”The reason why is that there are hundreds of rows and there are many references in the current project that refers to the 'selected rows'. So having a checkbox was recommended.”_ … ? How is adding a check box column going to help in this? Since the code has many references to the grids `SelectedRows` collection, how is adding a check box column going to help?

Comment: The point I am trying to make is that even if you added the check box column and “kept” the checked rows “selected” is NOT going to guarantee that the grids `SelectedRows` collection will ONLY contain rows that have the check box checked. If the user “selects” another row such that it’s check box is NOT checked, then that row will still be added to the grids `SelectedRows` collection. An important aspect of this is that YOU have NO control over the grids `SelectedRows` collection. Your code can not add or delete rows from the `SelectedRows` collection.

Comment: I am guessing, that is what you are wanting to avoid, is changing the many places in the code that have a reference to the grids `SelectedRows` collection. And I do not see how you can do this easily since YOU have no control over the grids `SelectedRows` collection. In other words, it may well be a lot of work if you changed ALL the places that refer to the grids `SelectedRows` collection and instead used ONLY the rows that have the check box checked, however, I do not see how you could do this without “changing” those many references to the `SelectedRows` collection to some other collection.

Comment: Lastly, I have a solution that keeps the row selected if the check box is checked, however, it still fails at keeping out rows that may be “selected” but the check box is not checked as described above. It sounds to me like you may have to change all those references to the `SelectedRows` if you only want the rows where the check box is checked. Let me know and I can post the check box solution as described, however it ONLY keeps the checked rows selected. It does NOT keep out rows that are selected yet the check box is NOT checked.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback and help! I wouldn't mind seeing what you came up with if that's okay. It sounds like it is a better route to just go through and change the selected row to use all the rows with only the checkbox =True  .  Do you have any references or recommendations to how I would change this. Currently the code uses DataGridSelectedRowCollection and defined through an If Statement on conditions of  DataGridView.SelectedRows